# no method error "merge" in Rails middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Hi I am building a Rails/Rack middleware for the Mailgun api, and doing a simple test for connection, which is fine in Postman with exact same params.

It is showing an error in test, Failure/Error: @app.call(env)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `merge!' for #<Mailgun::Tracking::MailLogger:0x0000557e6bc8bb50>
```

on running RSpec, and no merge method is attempted at all, so dont know where its come from. The api_key and endpoint are initialized in config/initialisers folder as per the Mailgun Tracking gem (which is being used) guidelines.

Only two other files used and code below.

MailLogger class under Mailgun::Tracking module, registered as middleware in app.

```
require 'logger'
require 'mailgun/tracking'
require 'rack/contrib'
require 'rack'
require 'byebug'

module Mailgun::Tracking
  class MailLogger
    def initialize(app, options = {
    "HTTP_X_MAILGUN_API_KEY" => ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'],
    "HTTP_X_MAILGUN_ENDPOINT" => ENV['MAILGUN_ENDPOINT']
    })
    @app = app
    @options = options
    end

    def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
    end
  end 
end
```

The RSpec test

```
require 'logger'
require "json"
require "rails_helper"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
require_relative "../../lib/middleware/mailgun/mailgun_tracking.rb"

RSpec.describe Mailgun::Tracking::MailLogger, type: 'Mailgun Webhook' do
  subject(:response) { app.call(env) }
  # env to pass in middleware, url endpoint & key
  let(:app) { described_class.new(Rails.application) }
  let(:env) { described_class.new(app, options = {
   "HTTP_X_MAILGUN_API_KEY" => ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'],
    "HTTP_X_MAILGUN_ENDPOINT" => ENV['MAILGUN_ENDPOINT']
  }) }

 it "returns a 200 status code" do
    expect(response).to eq([200, {}, ["OK"]])
  end
end
```

Am just looking for a 200, OK on connection, as I already get in Postman with the same header (api_key) and endpoint (events)

but throws this mysterious missing "merge" method error

Not encountered before.

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual code calling `merge!` is hidden in rack implementation and as such is filtered out from the error message. Your problem is that `env` you define in your test is not an instance of `Rack::Environment` but rather instance of your middleware. You can generate mocked environment instance using, for example, `Rack::MockRequest.env_for("/", method: :get)`

That being said, your unit test is currently testing the whole of the rack stack, including the routes and other middlewares. You can isolate your test better by using a mock application:

```
let(:app) { described_class.new(->(env) [200, {}, 'success']) }
```